# SFDX test run failing when output dir provided

Tags: unit-test, salesforcedx, sfdx-error

When I run `sfdx force:apex:test:run --codecoverage --resultformat json`, I get a normal output.

When I add an output dir `sfdx force:apex:test:run --codecoverage --resultformat json --outputdir ./test-output`, I get an `error:ERROR running force:apex:test:run:  Invalid time value`.

Any clue on what could be going on?

Comment: I ran the same command and it worked fine,

Comment: @NagendraSingh I appreciate that this is supposed to work. Just asking if anyone experienced the same problem.

Comment: are you on a Linux machine? I believe this is related to this [issue](https://github.com/forcedotcom/salesforcedx-apex/issues/213)